# refections of a candle in a glass

Tags: optics

I need help to unterstand this. 
[image: refections of candle]
Here you can see that within this glass the candle has two refections. The one behind the  fire of the candle is mirrored,  but the one in front of it is not. Why does this happen? To clarify: the mirrored fire is not up side down, it just dances in the opposite direction of the actual flame. 
Would be awesome if someone could explain.

Comment: There is also a 3rd reflection, at the rear rim or the glass, behind the flame, above the "mirrored" reflection.

Answer (score 2):

The mirrored reflection obviously reflects the back side of the flame which we cannot see directly.

What we see at the edge of the glass in front of the flame appears to have two distinct segments: top and bottom.

The top segments is likely to be a reflection off the top edge of the glass and, as such, it should be inverted upside down, although it is not obvious due to its narrow vertical span.

The bottom segment is likely to be a refraction, which should preserve both vertical and horizontal orientation of the flame, but, again, it is not obvious due to its small size.

Both segments are significantly distorted (compressed), since, unlike the mirror image on the back, they are produced by the edge of the glass, which has a small radius.